# Product of Gammas

Tags: special-functions, gamma-function

I am stuck and posting this out of desperation. Is there an approximation to the following product of Gamma functions:
$$\sum_{h=0}^{M}\frac{1}{\Gamma(h+1)\Gamma(M-h+1)}\frac{\Gamma(N-hd)}{\Gamma(-hd)}$$

where $d$ is a real value number, $N$ and $M$ are integers both growing to a large number (no where near $\infty$ though), and $N>M$.

**Note**: I have already tried replacing the gamma ratio using the Stirling approximation, but it requires adding two more $\Gamma$ terms: $\frac{\Gamma(N-hd)}{\Gamma(-hd)}\Rightarrow \frac{\Gamma(N-hd)}{\Gamma(N)}\frac{\Gamma(N)}{\Gamma(-hd)}\approx\frac{1}{N^{hd}}\frac{\Gamma(N)}{\Gamma(-hd)}$ while replacing gamma terms ratio with this approximation.

Comment: Does the Stirling formula give anything good? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)

Comment: Note that Stirling is a very good approximation for decently low values, unlike many other asymptotic relationships.

Comment: I just added a note to show that I tried the Stirling approximation already.

Comment: Using your same approximation, the whole expression becomes, approximately, $\frac{(M+1)^{h}(N-1)!}{M!h\Gamma(h)\Gamma(hd)}$. You didn't say what size $h$ and $d$ were, but there's less to compute as a gamma function this way, and depending on $h$, $\frac{(M+1)^{h}}{M!}$ has a cancellation in the coefficients. Not sure this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Disregarding convergence issues at the moment, the sum can be written as
$$ \frac{1}{\Gamma(-N)}\sum_{h=0}^{M}\frac{B(-N,N-hd)}{h!(M-h)!}=\frac{1}{M!\Gamma(-N)}\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{h=0}^{M}\binom{M}{h}x^{N-hd-1}(1-x)^{-N-1}\,dx $$
that by the binomial theorem equals
$$ \frac{1}{\Gamma(M+1)\Gamma(-N)}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{N-1}}{(1-x)^{N+1}}(1+x^{-d})^M\,dx $$
or
$$\boxed{\frac{1}{\Gamma(M+1)\Gamma(-N)}\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{(1+x^d)^M}{(x-1)^{N+1}}\,dx} $$
If $d=1$, that boils down to $-\frac{2^{M-N}\Gamma(N-M)\sin(M\pi)}{\pi}.$
 Otherwise, hypergeometric functions are involved.